# Like/Dislike function for Firebase

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

The system itself is pretty easy to understand but tricky to implement. Moreover, security reasons made me think how to do that.

I was thinking to make the function work in frontend firebase scripts simply doing everything there as checking if there is already like/dislike posted by this user and remove/add/switch if user clicked. The problem lies in security of this method: can't user create a new function which won't check if the like was posted?

And if that's possible, how should this system work? Right now my logic:

```
Clicked like:
    locally activate/deactivate like button and remove dislike active class if on
    check docs for this user/doc like
        `1`? -> remove this doc from collection
        `0`? -> switch to `1`, because `0` is dislike
        `undefined`? -> create doc with `vote: 1`
            change (+1/-1 or +2/-2) the value of post votes fields
```

Same for dislike. But this sounds really complicated as for such a small feature. Maybe it is possible to wave additional collection with user/votes without losing that level of security? Or using http-triggers may help with this somehow? This feature would be much easier on some PHP-like languages, so I am freaking out right now.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## Here are my assumptions.

1. You have a post with a unique id, let's call it `post_id`
2. You have a user with a unique id, let's call it `user_id`
3. There are 3 valid states: (Undefined), (Like), (Dislike)

## Basic process follows

To store the likes/dislikes, you create a collection called `feelings` which uses `post_id`+':'+`user_id` as it's document id (this makes it easy to look up).

Documents in `feelings` have a single field called `state` that stores `-1` for dislike, `1` for like.

As you mention, you can simply set or overwrite this value to whatever the user desires. If they decide to remove their 'feeling' and neither like or dislike, issue a delete command (this is cheaper than doing a write to set state to 0).

Use Cloud Functions to listen to the `feelings` collection and update the post documents like/dislike count based on how this state changes (or gets created/deleted).

Security Rules can enforce only allow states of `-1` and `1`, and if you're using Firebase Auth, you can trivially enforce only allowing the user matching `user_id` from being able to change state.

## What have you got now?

You now have a system with the following properties:

- Users can like and dislike posts
- Users can remove and/or change their like/dislikes
- Users can only like or dislike a post once - they cannot do it multiple times
- Only valid states (like, dislike) can be written to the database
- Only the user can update their likes/dislikes
- Scalable: Whether it's 10 posts, or millions of posts, this system will work

## Bonus credit

Using the same Cloud Functions event you register to update counts, you can also use this to add or remove from a list of user ids in both a like and dislike array. This would allow you to list out users who liked or disliked a post without have to query for each individual document in the `feelings` collection

Also remember that Cloud Functions has is a small chance it gets triggered more than once for a single event. If you want the counts to be guaranteed to be accurate, either make the code idempotent, or just have a manually triggered 'recount' process you can trigger if you or a user detects the counts seem off by one.

Comment: Never thought I can restrict the value of votes between -1 and 1, I like that one. But what do you mean by "Users can only like or dislike a post once - they cannot do it multiple times"? Usually, users can change their votes as much as they want, and how do I track if user can or can't change his vote here?

Comment: By multiple times, I mean the user cannot send requests to Firestore (bypassing your UI) that cause it to add 2 or more likes/dislikes for a single user. In the Cloud Function you get to check the new value with the previous value, so it the user has already 'liked' the post, you ignore any new 'like' updates. You could always choose to not allow people to change their state once set as well, just allow creates but not updates in security rules.

Comment: oh.. That's what you meant. I think a user should be able to place a like/dislike and then take it back if he wants to. So the second click on like would remove like.

Comment: I am sorry triggering this topic again but I have one more question if it is not hard for you to answer. How do you suggest to look for the number of votes on posts? To sum up all the votes from `feelings`? Isn't that a bit too much as for function that will update them in real time for like 15 posts per page? I feel like listener should listen to value on posts called likes/dislikes while it listens to the amount of likes and dislikes in `feelings` creating this messy chain structure.

Comment: @Telion I agree with you. Did you find a good solution to count the votes?

Comment: @vemund well, not really. Every time someone added a vote I was adding also +1 or -1 to post counter in its own document (additionally to the user likes log in feelings). So every time I need to calculate the votes they are already set. I don't think that's a good solution but that worked for me then.

Comment: Nice concept teach by @DanMcGrath. Can you please write some code for Cloud Functions as well as security rules for the same?

Comment: How to write security rules in firebase for the same concept you discussed @Dan McGrath. Like What if the user is the owner of the post and doing a like to its own post. How can I restrict that?

Answer (score 0):

If somebody's wondering for Realtime Database!

[image]

```js
var ref = firebase.database().ref(selectchapter + questionId + user_id);

ref.once("value", function (snapshot) {
            var exists = snapshot.val() !== null;
            if (!exists) {
               
                    firebase
                        .database()
                        .ref(
                            selectchapter +
                            questionId + user_id
                        )
                        .set({
                            status: 1
                        }).then(function () {
                            firebase.database().ref(q +
                                questionId + "likes").transaction(function (likes) {
                                return (likes || 0) + 1
                            });
                        });
                
            }
        });
```